# Pair of tangent lines from a point $(x_1,y_1)$ to a circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$

Tags: circles, conic-sections, tangent-line

> Pair of tangents drawn from a point $(x_1,y_1)$ to a circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ is given by
>   $$
> SS_1=T^2\implies(x^2+y^2-a^2)(x_1^2+y_1^2-a^2)=(xx_1+yy_1-a^2)^2
> $$

This is stated many where but most do not explain where does this come from.  It is asked in a similar post [The equation of a pair of tangents to a circle from a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484566/the-equation-of-a-pair-of-tangents-to-a-circle-from-a-point), but is it possible to get an intuition into how the expression gives pair of tangents drawn from a point $(x_1,y_1)$ to a basic form of circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ ?

Comment: See [Joachimstahl’s Notations](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml) There’s an equivalent expression and derivation using homogeneous coordinates and symmetric matrices.

Comment: Do some of your $a$'s need to be squared ?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here is an intuitive derivation that is based on a geometric construction:

From the diagram, we have $PS^2=(PQ-SQ)^2$, or,

$$PQ\cdot SQ = \frac 12 (PQ^2+SQ^2-PS^2)$$

With the right triangle relationships $PQ^2=OP^2-a^2$ and $SQ^2=OS^2-a^2$, we have,

$$PQ\cdot SQ = \frac 12 (OP^2+OS^2-PS^2)-a^2=OP\cdot OS\cos\alpha-a^2$$

Employ the vector product to expression the above as,

$$PQ\cdot SQ=\vec{OP} \cdot \vec{OS}-a^2\tag{1}$$

Next, use the coordinates for $S(x,y)$ and $P(x_1,y_1)$ to represent the line segments in (1),

$$PQ^2 = x_1^2+y_1^2-a^2,\>\>\>\>\>SQ^2 = x^2+y^2-a^2$$
$$\vec{OP} \cdot \vec{OS} = xx_1+yy_1$$

Plug above coordinate expressions into (1) to get the tangent equations

$$(x^2+y^2-a^2)(x_1^2+y_1^2-a^2)=(xx_1+yy_1-a^2)^2
$$
where we have squared the equation to include both tangents.