# Eqn of circle touching the pair of straight line $x^2-y^2+2y-1=0$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

I have already found out the separate eqns of the pair of straight lines  they are $x+y-1=0$ and $x-y+1=0$ and also their point of intersection of these two i.e. $(0,1)$.

Comment: Is x2 supposed to be $x^2?$  They are *not* the same.  If you have a pair of intersecting lines there are many circles that touch them both.  Please check the question.

Comment: @RossMillikan, yes that is supposed to be $x^2$, which is clear when we multiply the equation of lines he obtained.

Comment: @Martund: I feel people should make an effort to get the question right.  Beyond what you found, there are many circles tangent to both lines, not just one.

Comment: As RossMillikan noted, some data is missing. Two intersecting lines divide coordinate plane into four parts, each part contains infinitely many circles touching both lines.

Comment: Compare with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484566/the-equation-of-a-pair-of-tangents-to-a-circle-from-a-point

Comment: Insufficient condition if you want to find unique circle . Because there will be infinite circles possible touching these two lines.Center of all such circles will lie on angling bisectors of to lines I.e on lines y=1 and another infinite circles with center on x=0 .

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the equation of circle tangent to lines $x+y-1=0$ and $x-y+1=0$, note that the lines are symmetry about y axis , so it's center has a coordinate like $C(0, a); [1<a<∞] and [-∞<a<1]$ .C is the intersection of a line perpendicular to one of these lines and y axis. Now take an arbitrary point $A(x_A, y_A)$ on one of these lines ; find the equation of perpendicular and hence a. $R=AC$ is the radius of the circle and  the equation of a circle tangent at line at point  $A(x_A, y_A)$ is:

$x^2+(y-a)^2=R^2$

$R^2=(y_A-a)^2+ x^2_A$

That shows there can be many circle tangent to these line depending on values of a and R.

The two lines are also symmetry about line $y=1$.That is the center of circles can have coordinate like $O(x_O=b , 1)$. You can follow the same method to find center O for any arbitrary point  like $A(x_A, y_A)$ on each line. The equation of circle will be:

$(x-b)^2+(y-1)^2=R^2$

Where R can be found as:

$R^2=AO^2= (x_A-b)^2+(y_A-1)^2$

And b can be found by solving a system of equation resulted from intersection of a perpendicular from A and line $y=1$.

Comment: That's half of it.  Center of circle could be on $y=1$.

Comment: You are right, I edited the answer.