# Angle between tangents to circle given by $x^2 + y^2 -12x -16y+75=0$?

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

> Given the circle: $C(x,y)=x^2 + y^2 -12x -16y+75=0$, find the two tangents from origin

First, I get the line which passes through point of contact of tangents from origin using result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4011633/line-through-point-of-contact-of-tangents) which is :

$$ -12x-16y-2 \cdot 75 = 0$$

Or,

$$ 6x + 8y -75 =0 $$

Now, I use the result discussed in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1487589/688539), which says that pair of straight from point $(P)$ to conic is given as:

$$ C(0,0) C(x,y) =  (6x+8y-75)^2$$

This leads to:

$$ 75 (x^2 + y^2 -12x-16y+75) = (6x+8y-75)^2$$

$$ 0 = 75(x^2 +y^2 - 12 x - 16y +75) - (6x+8y-75)^2$$

For applying the result in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3977527/688539), then the formula

$$ a= 75 - 36,  b=75-64 , h= - \frac{(6 \cdot 8 \cdot 2 )}{2}$$

Or,

$$ a = 39, b= 11 , h=-48$$

$$ \tan \theta = \frac{2 \sqrt{(-48)^2-39 \cdot 11)}}{39+11} = \frac{2 \sqrt{5^4 \cdot 3}}{25} = 2 \sqrt{3}$$

However, the intended answer was:

$$ \tan \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} } $$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Bruh @AlbusDumbledore does this result have a name/ can you give a reference for it?

Comment: My god, there seems to be a formula for every single thing you can think for jee problems 

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore known problem? I didn't understand

Comment: @Buranian there is another fromula for that,$$x^2+y^2=\frac{a^2}{\sin^2( \theta/2)}$$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Omg how on earth is there a formula for every single thing

Comment: However, thank you for introducing me to these formulas , it is of much help. I'll try get my hands on that arihant book lol

Comment: The correct answer is $\tan\theta=\sqrt 3$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Not only I got algebraically, but also with GeoGebra https://imgur.com/ozSDIVG

Comment: @Raffaele you are correct ,i checked my book again the right formula was $$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=(g^2+f^2-c)\cot^2 (\theta/2)$$ thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake lies in using $6x+8y-75=0$ further instead of $-12x-16y+150=0$
in the formula. Correct way is to write:
$$C(0,0) C(x,y)=(-12x-16y+150)^2.$$
to get the correct answer.

Comment: Why should we write it like that? @Z Ahmed

Comment: This formula assumes to use equation of chord of contact as it is without taking anything common.  Check you get different result.

Comment: Fair, but why like that :?

Comment: Read your book for this point, there also they often don't write this crucial point. If you get 2x-4y-4=0 don't use $x-2y-2=0$. In fact if you do this mistake you many not get combined equation of pair of tangents. Otherwise the obtained quadratic of $x,y$ may represent a conic instead of pair of lines.There are other ways of doing this problem. you may leave out this formula.

Comment: @ZAhmed why exactly is it not plausible? Can you elaborate a bit about your last point regarding why it might result in a different conic

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution: Find the center of the given circle, which is (6, 8). The line from the center of the circle to the point of contact of one of the tangents is perpendicular to the tangent. Use this fact to get the equation of a new circle, which is $x^2-6x+y^2-8x=0$. Find where both circles meet. Find the angle between the vectors, which are the two points where the circles meet using the formula:$$\text{Angle} = \arccos\left(\frac{x_1x_2 + y_1y_2}{\sqrt{(x_1^2+y_1^2) \cdot (x_2^2+y_2^2)}}\right)$$

Comment: I don't get it why you went from this new circle to angle between vector, I Got till circle thing

Comment: Because the angle is taken from the origin, the points can be seen as vectors.

Comment: Subtract the equations of both circles and you get a linear equation (6x + 8y = 75) which can be plugged back into one of the circle equations to find the two points.

Comment: Wait, consider point on circle $(x,y)$ vector from origin to here is $<x,y>$ now, vector from radius to this point is $<x-a,y-b>$ , now dot is zero, I get equation of circle, but from what I understand there is only two points satisfying the original condition (from origin , bcoz circle only has two tangents)

Comment: Yes there are only two points. Let me type a full solution for you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Math777

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119362/discussion-between-math777-and-buraian).

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem! To understand why it fails , refer back to the derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1487589/688539), it was assumed that:

$$C(P) + \lambda T(P)^2 = 0$$

Where we are subbing in the coordinate of point $P$ into equation of circle, and we assumed that $T(P) = C(P)$ , now this is not true if we directly scale up the equation of tangents [(read Jocahimsthal's notation for understanding)](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml), now suppose we say,:

$$ T'(x,y) = \lambda T(x,y)$$

Then,

$$ \frac{T'(P)}{\phi} = T(x,y)$$

Or,

$$C(P) = \frac{T'(P)}{\phi} \tag{1} $$

And if we used scaled tangent equation in original equation

$$ C(P) +  \lambda (T'(P))^2=0 \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2),

$$ C(P) + \lambda ( \phi C(P) )^2 = 0$$

Or,

$$ -\frac{1}{\phi^2 C(P)} = \lambda$$

Which changes our tangent equation to:

$$ C(x,y) C(P) = \frac{T'(x,y) )}{\phi^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Expansion on Math777's answer, see [here first](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4013885/688539), the rest of the answer's idea can be understood in the following way:

Reference picture:

[image]

Fact: From any external point there exists two tangents to the circle, therefore there must be two tangents from the point $(0,0)$ to our circle since this point is external to our circle.

Now, the vector from origin to point of contact of tangent is perpendicular to radius vector because tangent and radius are perpendicular, there are two such points like this. These two points satisfy equation of the bigger diametric circle, hence these two points are the intersection of big diameteric circle and original one (See the linked post to understand the diameteric circle idea)

Answer (score 0):

A much more sane and simpler way:

[image]

Observe the right triangle created by the line segment from origin to center, and origin to the point which is tangent to circle. Since, tangent and radius are perpendicular, we can apply good ol' trignometery easily:

$$ \sin \theta = \frac{r}{OC}= \frac{5}{10}= \frac{1}{2}$$

Hence, the $ x= \frac{\pi}{6}$ , which makes total angle between tangent as $ x = \frac{\pi}{3}$

However, all the other answer are beautiful in demonstrating the different way of approaching the same problem.